# How to get English keybindings on localized Word

Tags: localization, microsoft-word

At work, I have a machine with a Norwegian Word 2010 installed.

It uses **localized keybindings**, e.g. Ctrl-K for Italics instead of Ctrl-I, since Italics is called *Kursiv* in Norwegian.

How can I change Word to English/US keyboard shortcuts?

*(As an, IMHO, interesting aside/rant: In Excel, us Norwegians have to write HVIS instead of IF.)*

Comment: I edited your post. I wasn't sure whether you also want the Excel keywords changed. I removed that, since you didn't mention them in the title, tags, and only in parentheses in the text.

Comment: You mean you don't want to search with Ctrl-B?

Comment: @DanielBeck: The solution is the same to both Excel and Word (and probably other Office tools aswell). Also I think you removed an important bit about him specifying that he wants to change the entire applications language to English (in the first paragraph), not just key bindings.

Comment: @ohaal That's what I'm not sure about, therefore the earlier comment. The question seemed to focus on **key bindings** and **Word**, with the rest *possibly* just being a rant.

Comment: @ohaal: I don't necessarily want the entire GUI to be English - since MS apparently, incredibly, charges money for that. But I CANNOT handle the keybindings.

Comment: @stolsvik If you disagree with the edit, feel free to undo it. But Excel keywords are either part of the question, or not. Your intent just wasn't clear with how you added them within parentheses at the end. Note that comments can be and should be freely deleted once they're no longer useful, so that's hardly a relevant issue.

Answer (score 4):

Go to

- Fil

  - Alternativer

    - Språk

      - Select Engelsk **[English]** as your preferred display language ("skjermspråk/visningsspråk") in the language priority box
      - Click "Bruk som standard"

---

This is a little hard to explain without including Norwegian language, but in English, it would look something like this:

- File

  - Options

    - Language

      - Select **[English]** as your preferred display language in the language priority box
      - Click "Set as Default"

---

*Note: You'll have to do a restart of Word after performing these changes*

Comment: I only have Norwegian there, and I apparently have to *buy* add-ons? It must (?) be possible to only change the keybindings, if only manually, not the entire GUI (which seemingly costs money)?

Comment: In Office365, looks like I get English for free even with a Swedish-bought Office.  Setting the whole app language to English does get me English keyboard shortcuts.  But it is annoying that there is no way to have a native-language app with non-native keyboard shortcuts.